# How to use math symbols below an underbrace?

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to use `\alpha` below an underbrace but it doesn't appear, in fact it also breaks the rest of the pdf. Especifically I'm doing this:

```
\underbrace{x^3}_\text{ \alpha }
```

What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: Why `\text`?  Simply `$\underbrace{x^3}_{\alpha}$` works just fine.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\alpha` is *not* `\text`. Just use `\underbrace{x^3}_{\alpha}`.